# PHP error while sending email - mail not received

Tags: php, email

I'm writing a program in PHP using Apache server, where I want to send email. I have installed Apache server on my Ubuntu machine which works fine. I've created a PHP email page using PHP's email function.

Acknowledgment is also coming but still I am unable to see email in my inbox. So please help me to do this because I want to use this functionality in my website's contact page.

Comment: How are we supposed to find the problem when you don't include any of the code you are using? Please include your code and we can try to help you out.

Comment: It's just "PHP", not "(Personal Home Page)", which [isn't even the official meaning anymore](http://php.net/manual/en/preface.php).

Comment: Actually, I never read anybody ever referring to that name, except in books about PHP's history :D. I've edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking the log files.

A possible problem could be that authentication fails when connecting to the email - server. The email - server has to be configured properly so that PHP knows how to connect to it.

If you install an email server (MTA) on a machine at home it will probably not work because emails from dynamic IP addresses might be rejected as possible spam. So, you might need a provider for it, but you can try to use the same provider and account that you ordinaryly use for sending emails.